# Is there a language that takes advantage of massively parallel computers?

Tags: parallel-processing, programming-languages

There's a company that have/are developing a very parallel computer called Parallella. It looks like it has lots of potential, but it runs some C style language.

Q. Has anyone written a language specifically to take advantage of massively parallel computers like this?

- Clause 1. It has to be a <strike>managed</strike> garbage collected language.
- Clause 2. It has to make it very easy to write parallel code without requiring the developer to look after low-level locking.
- Clause 3. Bonus points for functional languages.
- Clause 4. Super bonus points for languages with lambdas.

Comment: Have you taken a look to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concurrent_and_parallel_programming_languages ?

Comment: +1 loads of languages, -1 loads of languages lol, seriously though, good link, will have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a definitely languages that have been designed to deal with the rising popularity of parallel computing. Parallel processors have sky rocketed in popularity since the death of [Moore's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law). Support for better parallel computing in programming languages has followed quickly in its path.

My personal recommendation would be either [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) or [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). Both are functional languages which have made great strides in parallel and concurrent computing leveraging their functional nature to gain advantages. Haskell has a really nice book called [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026365.do) by Simon Marlow. I've read it and it's excellent. Clojure has also been built from the ground up with concurrency in mind. An interesting new player in this space is [Julia](http://julialang.org/), but I can't say I know much about it at all.

As for clause 1, I don't know what a managed language means. EDIT: What you're calling a managed language is more commonly called [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) language. You might want to use that term to help get more effective answers. Also all the languages I recommended have garbage collection.

As for clause 2, Haskell definitely makes parallel computing fairly automatic without any worrying about low level concepts or locking. There is a simple function called 'par' which allows the programmer to annotate two computations to be executed in parallel. The semantics guarantee that the expressions be evaluated when they're necessary and since the computations are functional they are guaranteed not to interact in non-thread-safe ways.

As for clause 3, you're on the right track to be looking for a functional language. Functional subcomputations have automatic thread safety which pays big dividends when it comes to ensuring parallel execution doesn't cause problems. It can't cause any if the computations are functional.

As for clause 4, good luck finding a functional language that doesn't have lambda ;) EDIT: It's not, strictly speaking, part of the definition of a functional language because there is no formal definition for what a functional programing language is. Informally I think a lot of people would mention it as one of the most important features. Concatenative languages or languages that are based on tacit programming (aka point-free style) can be functional and get away with not having lambda. I wouldn't be surprised if the K language didn't have lambda despite being functional. Also, I know for sure combinatory logic (which is the basis for K) does not have lambda. Though combinatory logic is just a theoretical basis and not a practical programming language.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for the links too. A managed language just means that memory management is automatically taken care of, no need to free memory or keep reference counts or whatnot.
Do all functional languages have lambdas then? Is it part of the definition? I work with Java, and would remove substantial parts of my body to have lambdas lol

Comment: What you're calling a managed language is more commonly called garbage collected language. You might want to use that term to help get more effective answers. Also all the languages I recommended have garbage collection.

Comment: The only quibble I have with this answer is that, on the massively parallel computers I have worked on,  I have never seen a line of Haskell, Clojure or, for that matter, any other modern functional language.  I've seen a lot of C, Fortran and C++ and a little Python and Java.  This -- http://www.hpcwire.com/2011/04/14/compilers_and_more_exascale_programming_requirements/ -- is illuminating.

Comment: The original post does not ask "Which programming languages are most common in high-performance applications". C and Fortran have been around forever and are therefor entrenched as the standard for many applications. The original post asks which languages are designed "specifically to take advantage of massively parallel computers". Therefor this answer a lot more appropriate than saying "C or Fortran".

Comment: Massively parallel usually means "distributed".   A major feature of programming languages for such systems is either explicit or implicit message passing to distribute data across the CPUs, and necessary computation partitioning and synchronization    AFAICT,  none of the languages listed in this answer handle that.  Check out PGAS languages at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concurrent_and_parallel_programming_languages.

Answer (score 0):

@High Performance Mark - Python is most definitely not a parallel language - the global interpreter lock (GIL) ensures that all Python threads run sequentially (unless they call system functions, when the GIL is released). The best you can hope for with Python is concurrency. Python is great for orchestrating other programs, which might be where you saw it - the GIL doesn’t apply then.

Neither C++ nor C were designed for parallel programming, but newer versions have cobbled some mechanics together - as has Fortran. Formular Translator, better known as an address space manipulator or C without the safeguards. Seriously, the only reason to use Fortran is because you need to use a Fortran library. These are easily recognizable because they are streaked with the blood, sweat and tears left behind by decades of those that went before. Bulletproof, but at what a cost.

Oh, and I know you weren’t saying this, but C, C++ and Fortran violate Clauses 1 and 2.

Listen to mmachenry: the holy clause, the sainted clause, or, as the Spanish would say, the Santa Clause, is to use a functional language. If Parallela needs to sell to Lawrence Livermore, they can write a binary interface to Fortran with the time they’ll save.

NB: Clojure compiles to Java byte code, so if Clojure fits the profile, Java or Scala may also fit. Both have functional extensions.